# Angular 4 - Cannot add/remove sealed array elements

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am getting the following error trying to insert elements to an array:

> Cannot add/remove sealed array elements

I get the data using apollo-angular (GraphQL client). The data is retrived just fine.

Here is my code : 
main.html:

```
<div class="chats">
    <chat *ngFor="let chat of activeChats; let i = index" [chat]="activeChats[i]" (close)="removeChat(i)"></chat>
</div>
```

Chat component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html'
})
export class ChatComponent {

  @Input() chat : Chat

  constructor(
      private chatService : ChatService
  ) {}

  getNextPage(){
    this.chatService.getMessages(this.chat.id, this.chat.messages[0].sentTime).subscribe(msgs=>{
       // The error thrown here
       this.chat.messages.splice(0,0,...(msgs || []));
    })
  }
}
```

Chat data sample structure :

```
{
  id : "234234234",
  messages : [
     {id:"2341112", sentTime:"2017-07-05T17:14:07.396Z"},
     {id:"2341342", sentTime:"2017-06-05T17:14:07.396Z"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: you get the data from service and then clear it up? Also update your sample json file

Comment: I get the data from a service calling graphql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the apollo-client package, I'm using to communicate with my GraphQL server and fetch the data.

It seems that apollo-client automatically deep freeze all server responses.
I've opened a relavent issue on their github repo:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1909

Answer (score 2):

In your service when you receive a response:

instead:

```
this.messages = result.data.nodes;
```

use:

```
this.messages = [...result.data.nodes];
```